# Using lock in Hangfire executed ASP.Net code

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

I am using hangfire in an ASP.Net MVC project to manage longrunning background job.

I am trying to use lock statement block for database operation. Here is my lock statement code-

```
public class LockedTransaction
{
    private Object thisLock = new Object();

    public LockedTransaction() { }

    public void UpdateCustomerBalance(long CustomerId, decimal AmountToDeduct, string ConnectionString)
    {
        lock (thisLock)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)) 
                {
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
                    {
                        command.Connection = connection;
                        command.Transaction = transaction;

                        command.CommandText = "SELECT Balance FROM Customer WHERE Id=" + CustomerId;
                        var userBalance = Convert.ToDecimal(command.ExecuteScalar());
                        userBalance = userBalance - AmountToDeduct;

                        command.CommandText = "UPDATE Customer SET Balance=" + userBalance + "  WHERE Id=" + CustomerId;

                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        transaction.Commit();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I'm calling the above code-

```
foreach (var queue in queues)
{
     queue.Send();
     LockedTransaction lockedTransaction = new LockedTransaction();
     lockedTransaction.UpdateCustomerBalance(queue.CustomerId, queue.cost, "ConnectionString");
}
```

The problem is, database value is not updated as expected. For example, I have 5 queues as follows -

```
queue[0].cost = 0.50;
queue[1].cost = 0.50;
queue[2].cost = 0.50;
queue[3].cost = 0.50;
queue[4].cost = 0.50;
```

Database value should be deducted 2.5 (cost total) after completing the loop. But it's not happening. Sometimes deducted value is 2.00, sometimes 1.5, etc.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lock object (`thisLock`) is an instance property. And cause in `foreach` loop you create a new instance of `LockedTransaction` for each element in the queue, `lock` doesn't prevent concurrent executions (each calling of UpdateCustomerBalance method uses own lock object).

Changing `thisLock` to static property should help you:

```
private static Object thisLock = new Object();
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. Should I change LockedTransaction class t o static?

Comment: @s.k.paul - you may use static/singleton class if it suitable for you. My main point is that you should use `one` lock object among your transactions.